# Understanding the ConvertToCrm method C#

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I am trying to find some explanatory material for the "ConvertToCrm" method in C#.

If I F12 it I get:

```
 public void ConvertToCRM(U source, T destination)
        {
            ConvertToCRM(source, destination, InnerConvertToCRM);
        }

    protected abstract void ConvertTo(U source, T destination);
    protected abstract void ConvertFrom(T source, U destination);
```

-Which in itself is not explanatory enough for a rookie like myselv. At least not when it stands alone.

I have tried to google it, but come up very empty handed. there is nothing in MSDN or the MS CRM Manual that helps either.
If someone have a link or similar to explain this in more detail, it would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard method called `ConvertToCRM`. I suggest you F12 further into the `ConvertToCRM` overload that takes three arguments which we see called above.

Comment: Aah, I thought it was a standard method, due to the generic name. Thanks